# Problema con paso de datos con ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax, postgresql

Tengo el siguiente problema: necesito cargar un select a partir de otro cosa que es sencilla con ajax, si, pero he llegado a una parte del codigo en el cual hace el cambio pero no me devuelve los datos requeridos, adjunto el codigo de mi consulta y de mi ajax.

**Ajax:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var fecha = $('#fecha');
     var fecha_sel = $('#fecha_sel');

      $('#vessel').change(function(){
          var vessel_name = $(this).val();

          if (vessel_name !== '') {
             $.ajax({
                  data: {vessel_name:vessel_name},
                  dataType: 'html',
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: 'consultas.php'
                  }).done(function(data){
                       fecha.html(data);
                       fecha.prop('disable', false);
                       });
                     }else{
                       fecha.val('');
                       fecha.prop('disable', true);
                     }
                 });
       });
```

Y esta es mi consulta:

```
<?php
require_once 'conexion/conexion.php'; 
$vessel_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'vessel_name'); 
   if($vessel_name != ''){ 
      if(!$dbconn){
         die("<br/>Sin conexi&oacute;n.");
      }
$sql = 'SELECT "TIMESTAMP_UTC1", "TIMESTAMP_UTC2" FROM vessel_complete WHERE "VESSEL_NAME" = '.$vessel_name.' ORDER BY "TIMESTAMP_UTC1" ASC';  
$query2 = pg_query($dbconn, $sql);
$filas = pg_fetch_all($query2);
pg_close($dbconn);
}
?>

<option value="">- Seleccione -</option>
<?php foreach($filas as $op): //creamos las opciones a partir de los datos obtenidos ?>
<option value="<?= $op["TIMESTAMP_UTC1"] ?>"><?= $op["TIMESTAMP_UTC1"] ?> 
</option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar, no comprendo el porque no me llena el select con otros datos que no sean - Selecciona -

Comment: Hola, tienes un error muy simple, olvidaste un `?>` en la linea `<?php foreach($filas as $op):`, deberia ser `<?php foreach($filas as $op): ?>`, eso es todo.

Comment: Si te fijas al final del comentario se encuentra el ?> por lo que no puede ser eso.

Comment: También en la consulta no debes usar  comillas dobles para referenciar los campos, funcionaria con: `'$sql = 'SELECT TIMESTAMP_UTC1, TIMESTAMP_UTC2 FROM vessel_complete WHERE VESSEL_NAME = '.$vessel_name.' ORDER BY TIMESTAMP_UTC1 ASC';`

Comment: No sobra el último `</option>` ?

Comment: Usa el inspector de código para verificar si te está mostrando algún error... Por lo pronto intenta cambiando las comillas dobles por simples y agrega `;` al final de cada variable, copia esta línea: `<option value="<?= $op['TIMESTAMP_UTC1']; ?>"><?= $op['TIMESTAMP_UTC1']; ?> </option>`

Comment: El problema es que postgresql necesita que lo pase como mayuscula, en la base de datos solo me lee los campos con " " por lo que utilice comilla simple ( ' ) para iniciar la consulta y " " para los campos de a tabla, pero dejame intentar lo de DjCrazy

Comment: He realizado los cambios que propuso DjCrazy pero no he tenido éxito alguno, como comente anteriormente, la base de datos me pide los " ".

Comment: `postgresql`? en la pregunta no lo mencionaste, o quizás no presté atención... agrega la etiqueta para que llegue a otros usuarios que tengan experiencia con este `DBM`